# A function that adds letters from a text into a dictionary without punctionation

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have wrote a function that adds letters to a dictionary but when i run it in the termianl it keeps adding punctionation to it. I have tried putting "and var != ',' and var != '-'" etc but it doesn't work and i cant figure out why

```
i = 0

while i < len(text):
    for var in text[i]
        if var not in d:
            d[var] = 1
        else:
            d[var] += 1
    i += 1
return(d)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share some input and expected output. Are you trying to make a frequency count of letters only? If so, `import collections, re` and use `collections.Counter(re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z]", s))`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so that we can better understand your issue

Comment: @ggorlen thank you! and yes! I am running it against a text file and i watch to put all the letters into a dictionary and no punctunation

Comment: Please change your code example into a piece of code that we can execute. We see a `return` but we see no `def`. Also we see no definition of `d`. So your code does not compile. We cannot test it.

Answer (score 2):

IMO the most pythonic solution to your task is:

```
from collections import Counter

def dict_letters(text):
    return Counter(c for c in text if c.isalpha()).items()
```

I assume you want to count the different characters in `text`. For counting there is the very useful `Counter` class in python. By using `isalpha` we ask every character `c` if it is a letter or punctuation.

(Because your code so far does not compile, this is just a guess.)

Answer (score -1):

Using isalpha() is one way to do it:

```
def dict_letters(text):
    i = 0
    d = {}
    while i < len(text):
        for var in text[i]:
            if var.isalpha():
                if var not in d:
                    d[var] = 1
                else:
                    d[var] += 1
        i += 1
    return(d)

print(dict_letters("This is a Text 1, this is a number 1"))
```

You don't need a while loop to loop through the text as Python treats strings as list of character

```
def dict_letters(text):
    d = {}
    for chr in text:
        if chr.isalpha():
            if chr not in d:
                d[chr] = 1
            else:
                d[chr] += 1
    return(d)

print(dict_letters("This is a Text 1, this is a number 1"))
```

Python distinguishes between capital letters and small letters, if you want it to combine lower and upper case letters:

```
def dict_letters(text):
    d = {}
    for chr in text:
        if chr.isalpha():
            if chr.lower() not in d:
                d[chr.lower()] = 1
            else:
                d[chr.lower()] += 1
    return(d)

print(dict_letters("This is a Text 1, this is a number 1"))
```

Comment: We should not teach newbies for-if-if-else solutions when there are faster alternatives from the standard library. Reinventing the wheel is slow and error-prone.

Comment: @LydiavanDyke I assumed he's trying to learn different concepts rather than write production ready code. I might be wrong. I only was trying to help.

Comment: Of course, we all want to help. But in my opinion it is also important to put the fixed attempt into perspective. "This would fix your code, but you should not do it like this" should be the answer :)

Comment: Don't forget: Other people in the future might stumble across this SO answer. They might just copy the proposed solution... into their production code.